# interspire openers count bigger than

Tags: mysql, sql

So i use interspire for newsletters, and i wanted to extract the emails from the members on list 13, 18 and 24 that opened emails more than 5 times.
Interspire has a segment function that allows me to create a segment for people that opened more than once, this is the SQL:

```
select distinct 
    `email_list_subscribers`.`emailaddress` AS `emailaddress` 
from 
    (`email_list_subscribers` join `email_stats_emailopens`) 
where 
    ((`email_stats_emailopens`.`subscriberid` = `email_list_subscribers`.`subscriberid`) 
    and (`email_list_subscribers`.`listid` = 18))
```

This one, grabs all the users that opened the campaigns on list 18 so i can make a segment.

But i want to do is extract the users that opened more than 5 times on those 3 lists
13,18,24

i did this small sql but takes ages to execute and i had to stop it after 20 minutes:

```
SELECT email_stats_emailopens.subscriberid
  FROM email_stats_emailopens ,
email_list_subscribers
 GROUP BY email_stats_emailopens.subscriberid
HAVING COUNT(email_stats_emailopens.subscriberid) > 3
limit 1
```

Anyone knows how to do it ? I'm not very good with sql.

Comment: No join condition needed?

Comment: is the 5 times all lists included or 5 times in each of these lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, this should give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
    EO.subscriberid 
FROM 
    email_list_subscribers S
INNER JOIN email_stats_emailopens EO
ON S.subscriberid = EO.subscriberid
where  S.listid IN (13,18,24)
GROUP BY EO.subscriberid  , S.listid
HAVING COUNT(1) > 5
```

Let me know if this does not meet your needs.

Comment: Note that this will return only users who have opened emails more than 5 times in each of the lists. If you are just looking for more than 5 times cummulative of all your lists. Change `GROUP BY EO.subscriberid  , S.listid` to `GROUP BY EO.subscriberid `